# Make Samba Share Accessible Outside of Nautilus

Tags: samba

I have a samba share on my network. It works fine and I can access it via Nautilus however I am not able to access it from other apps such as Thunderbird when attaching a file or in Firefox when trying to upload a file. The samba share is open, it doesn't require a username or password.

What is the best way to configure my system so all applications can see and browse my samba share?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the most user friendly way, you it's possible to mount a cifs (samba) share thanks to cifs-utils. Here the full process:

```
# Install the cifs-utils package
apt install cifs-utils

# Create a folder in your home (replace folder by any name you wish)
mkdir $HOME/folder

# Mount the folder (replace again folder and your_user).
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share $HOME/folder -o username=your_user,uid=$(id -u $USER)
```

> Note: this is not persistent, you may need to do a script if you wish an automount.

Comment: Thanks but when I try to mount with cifs I always get host not found. Also, I don't believe cifs will fuse the samba drive with the filesystem. I am currently fusing the samba drive with the filesystem with this command: sudo smbnetfs ~/Shared -o allow_other, it works but I am hoping there is a better, easier way.

Comment: If you have an error 'share not found' , then you most probably mistypped the server's or the share's.  Maybe, as a check, you could use the IP adress of your server: `sudo mount -t cifs //IP/share $HOME/folder -o username=guest`